# Making external display DPI settings permanent

Tags: multi-monitor, display, xrandr, resolution

System: Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon.

Hardware: Laptop screen: 3840x2160 + HDMI screen 1920x1080;

[GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit): [NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/), [GeForce GTX 1060](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1060/), [Max-Q Design](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/gaming-laptops/max-q/), 6 GB [VRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_RAM_(dual-ported_DRAM))

---

I have enabled Double DPI in General settings. It works fine for the laptop display, but now I connected an external FullHD display, the things on it are twice as large.

I currently use the following command to correct the scaling:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --scale 2x2
```

---

My intention is to make this permanent and persistent on reboots etcetera.

How and in what file can I do this?

---

I have tried to look for an `xorg.conf`, but this is what I only get:

```
$ locate -i xorg.conf

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-quirks.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-radeon.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-prime.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-wacom.conf
/usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-video-intel/xorg.conf
/usr/share/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/xorg.conf.d.5.gz
```

---

Note, that I use Nvidia, so these 2 might be relevant:

```
$ cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf

Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

and this one:

```
$ cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-prime.conf

# DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED BY gpu-manager

Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "Nvidia Prime"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
    Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"
    ModulePath "/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the solution in
https://enochtsang.com/articles/scaling-two-monitors-differently-on-linux-mint
?

In your case, create a file called `.xsession` in your home directory, in the terminal you can do that with `touch ~/.xsession`

Second, open it with a text editor and paste this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

xrandr --output HDMI-0 --scale 2x2
```

Make the file executable `chmod +x ~/.xsession`

Add it as a startup application in **Startup Applications** >> ( + ) >> Custom command.

```
Name: Displays
Command: /home/your_user_name/.xsession
Comment: 
Startup delay: 0
```

Also, it wouldn't hurt to make some noise in the Mint forums or on Github, so the Linux Mint team implement this feature once and for all.